# How do I update a variable value in python?

Tags: python

```
import os

i = 1

PATH = "C:\\Capture "+ str(i)

isFile = os.path.exists(PATH)

while isFile == 0:
    
  i = i + 1
```

How can I make **'i'**, inside the while loop, update the value of **'str(i)'**?

Comment: Do `PATH = r"C:\Capture "+str(i)` in the loop again.

Comment: The value of *str(i)* has been used in the initial string concatenation. There is no variable storing that value. You would need to reconstruct it

Comment: While `False == 0` in Python, it's not idiomatic to treat `bool` values as if they were `int` values. use `while not isFile:` instead.

Comment: @balloon21 As far as I read it, you'd be better off using [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir). Using this function, you could list all files and directories in `C:` and then look for your "capture files". This would (1) most likely be faster and (2) you would not need to use a while loop that could end up in an infinite loop (i.e. generally bad practise).

Comment: also can try glob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
import os
        
i = 1
is_file = False
        
        
def check_file_exits():
    global i
    global is_file
            
    path = f"C:\\Capture{i}"
    is_file = os.path.exists(path)
        
        
while not is_file:
    i += 1
    check_file_exits()
```

I don't suggest the above method because as Andre suggests this is a bad practice and can lead to an infinite loop, thus you can do as follows:

```
import os

def check_file_exits(file_name):
    files = os.listdir(path="path")

    for file in files:
        if file == file_name:
           return True
    
    return False

check_file_exits("file_name_you_want_to_find")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are doing, you need to put the PATH, isFile variable inside of the while in order for that be dynamic

otherwise you are just checking once

```
import os    
i = 1   


while isFile == 0:
  PATH = "C:\Capture "+str(i)    
  isFile = os.path.exists(PATH)    
  i = i + 1
```

This is based on your code, not sure the requirement you have but take this as starting point

Comment: "isFile" will be undefined here.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from glob import glob

glob("C:\Capture *")
```

The glob function is useful for your case.